# Pantheon is now sponsoring Drupal Answers: Sorry there wasn’t a heads up

Tags: discussion, announcement, site-sponsorship

As you may have noticed [Pantheon](https://pantheon.io/) is now sponsoring Drupal Answers. We failed to give the [prior heads-up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376530/what-goes-into-site-sponsorships-on-se) that we typically do when a sponsorship is about to launch.

We do have a process internally between teams to inform us when sponsorships are confirmed and a message was lost between stakeholders. There were some recent shifting of teams involved in this process, and no matter how iron clad you think processes are, things will slip through the cracks.

We genuinely apologize for any confusion or inconvenience this may have caused. We are currently looking for the holes that this process fell into so that we can patch them up and restore order for future processes.

### What you need to know about this sponsorship

Pantheon will be running their sponsorship from now until **August 28, 2023**.

### How and where will the sponsorship be displayed?

The sponsorship can be found on the right side of the header at the top of the site, just as it looks now.

### What else changes?

Not a thing! Borrowing from [the original MSE announcement on sponsorships](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307861/site-sponsorships-bringing-resources-back-to-stack-exchange):

First — sponsors do not own these Q&A sites. Sponsors work alongside our communities who ultimately build these sites. Communities ask the questions; communities create the tags; communities conduct elections as they do now, and we are not renaming our current sites like a garish sport stadium to the highest bidder. Any ads a sponsor submits still have go through our crazy-strict ad editorial process… as it has always been. Companies do not have access to personal data, and all Q&A content remains irrevocably licensed under Creative Commons for sharing and attribution.

### What if I've found a design glitch/bug?

If something looks off, please report it as a [bug](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) so we can investigate and squash it.
That's all. If you have any other questions or concerns, please leave them as answers below.

Lastly, thank you. These types of partnerships help us bring more resources to our communities, and they wouldn't be possible without the work you've put into making Drupal successful.

If you have any questions or concerns, please let me know.

*PS You weren’t alone. This also happened on [DevOps](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393/hashicorps-is-now-sponsoring-devops-sorry-there-wasnt-a-heads-up) and I posted there as well. I offered a photo of my pet rabbit Cleo as part of our apology. I do the same here.*

[image: a brown lop rabbit]

Comment: The end date of the sponsorship changed to August 28th. I've edited the post to reflect that.